# Versions of Gödel's incompleteness theorems

Tags: logic, incompleteness

This continues my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308049/what-does-the-expression-contains-arithmetic-in-the-second-g%C3%B6del-incompletenet).

I think the following versions of Gödel's incompleteness theorems must be true, but I can't find references. I would be happy if specialists could help.

To give accurate formulations I need the following definition which is a modification of Shoenfield's construction of interpretation of a theory in another theory [[Shoenfield](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568811357), 4.7].

Let $S$ and $T$ be formal theories over the predicate logic. Let us say that $S$ has an *interpretation* in $T$, if

- the alphabet of $T$ contains the alphabet of $S$,
- to each propositional symbol $p$ in the signature of $S$ we assigned an extended propositional symbol $p'$ (of the same arity) in $T$ in the sense of [[Kunen](https://books.google.ru/books/about/The_Foundations_of_Mathematics.html?id=_B_oQQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y),II.15.1]
- to each functional symbol $f$ in the signature of $S$ we assigned an extended functional symbol $f'$ (of the same arity) in $T$, again in the sense of [[Kunen](https://books.google.ru/books/about/The_Foundations_of_Mathematics.html?id=_B_oQQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y),II.15.1]
- in the arising correspondence between formulas $\varphi\mapsto\varphi'$ each axiom $\varphi$ in $S$ turns into a theorem $\varphi'$ in the theory $S'$ that appears as an extension by definitions of $T$.

The versions of Gödel's theorems I am interested in are the following:

> Theorem 1. Suppose $T$ is a consistent theory where the Peano arithmetic has an interpretation. Then $T$ is incomplete.
>
> Theorem 2. Suppose $T$ is a consistent theory where the Peano arithmetic has an interpretation. Then the proposition that $T$ is consistent is not deducible in $T$.

Questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. If yes, where is it written?
3. If no, then perhaps it is possible to modify the formulations so that they become true?

Comment: The first version is certainly false. You need some limitations on recursive enumerability. Otherwise take the theory of any model of PA.

Comment: Asaf, I don't understand. Suppose I take a model in ZFC, what is wrong with it?

Comment: You can also take PA itself. An example is not a proof...

Comment: I thought, you give a counterexample?

Comment: I did give a counterexample.

Comment: You should give it as an answer.

Comment: See [Godel's Incompleteness Th](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) : "one must first explain the key concepts essential to it, such as “formal system”, “consistency”, and “completeness”. Roughly, a formal system is a system of axioms equipped with rules of inference, which allow one to generate new theorems. The set of axioms is required to be finite or at least decidable, i.e., there must be an algorithm (an effective method) which enables one to mechanically decide whether a given statement is an axiom or not." ...

Comment: ... If this condition is satisfied, the theory is called “recursively axiomatizable”, or, simply, “axiomatizable”.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm expanding your comment into an answer, since I think it will help the OP and they're online right now; but since you got there first, if you'd like to post an answer let me know and I'll take mine down.

Answer (score 4):

This is an expansion on Asaf's answer. I am at this point rather confused about the OP's specific point of confusion, so I'll frame this answer in a purely formalist manner: the following argument is naturally expressible in the language of, and provable from, ZFC. If the OP doubts this, please point to a *specific* concern.

---

Suppose $M$ is a structure - that is, a set together with some functions, relations, and constants on that set named by symbols in some language $\Sigma$. Then associated to $M$ is the **theory** of $M$ - the set $$Th(M)=\{\varphi\in Sentence(\Sigma): M\models\varphi\}$$ of sentences true in $M$. This is a complete theory, since for every sentence $\varphi$ we have $M\models\varphi$ or $M\models\neg\varphi$.

*Note that this is a fundamental difference between structures and theories: for a theory $T$, of course we need **not** have $T\models\varphi$ or $T\models\neg\varphi$ for all sentences $\varphi$.*

Now if $M$ is a complicated enough structure - say, $M=(\mathbb{N}; +, \times)$ - then $Th(M)$ will interpret (say) PA. *Note that I'm speaking of an interpretation of one **theory** in another **theory**, not about a structure in a theory, a theory in a structure, or a structure in a structure; there are many kinds of interpretation, and this is why in my opinion it's unhelpful most of the time to think of models as a kind of interpretation. So I'll keep using the word "structure" to talk about an individual, well, "structure."*

So your formulation of Goedel's incompleteness theorem is wrong: for certain structures $M$, the theory $Th(M)$ is a complete theory which interprets PA.

Examining the proof of Goedel's incompleteness theorem in detail *(which one should always do when one is interested in generalizing something)*, we see that the crucial facts about PA (or whatever theory we're applying it to) are:

- PA-provability is definable, and
- basic facts about PA-provability are provable inside PA.

This winds up meaning that the theory has to be *recursively axiomatized*. The following is a true statement:

> If $T$ is a recursively axiomatized theory which interprets PA, then either $T$ is incomplete or $T$ is inconsistent.

*(Technically you need a twist on Goedel's argument to conclude this, provided by [Rosser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick); Goedel's original argument had an additional "correctness" assumption on $T$, namely [$\omega$-consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory).)*

A similar point holds for the second incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Noah, as far as I understand, my statements will be true if I replace there "Suppose $T$ is a recursively axiomatizable consistent theory" instead of "Suppose $T$ is a consistent theory", right?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Yes, that's correct (and is basically what I said in the bolded part at the end of my answer).

Comment: Oh! That is fine! This is indeed helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Noah is it possible that you know a reference? That would resolve all the rest problems for me.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov The requirement of recursive axiomatizability is stated clearly in every text I know. For instance, [this is how Wikipedia states the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem) - note the passage "where "formal system" includes the assumption that the system is effectively generated." Meanwhile the phrase "a certain amount of elementary arithmetic can be carried out" is usually left to the reader to interpret; I don't off the top of my head know a text which explicitly defines it but I'm sure there is one. (cont'd)

Comment: Btw, I'm going to edit my very first response to your original question to (hopefully) make it more palatable.

Comment: I understood already, that you are a saint. :)

Comment: Although I can't live without a reference to these two results. I do need a book or a paper.

Comment: Noah, among the standard examples - PA, ZFC, GB, MK,... - are there  theories which are not recursively axiomatized?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Nope, all of those are recursively axiomatizable. By the way, I think the right book for you would be [Peter Smith's excellent text](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-G-f6dels-Cambridge-Introductions-Philosophy/dp/1107606756). I think the following sections would be relevant: 

 - Weak: 5, 7 (informal notion of “enough arithmetic”)

 - Stronger: 16, 19 (on capturing functions), 26 (beyond arithmetic)

 - Best, maybe: 36 (best version of the theorem)

 - Possibly related: 33, 35

Comment: I don't have the text on hand, though, so I can't comment specifically. Here's a quick test to tell if a theory is recursively axiomatized: can you tell whether a given sentence is an axiom of the theory? If so, it's recursively axiomatized. For instance, PA has an infinite collection of induction axioms; however I can easily recognize whether a sentence is one of these since the induction axioms are exactly those of a certain easily-recognizable form. Similarly with the replacement and separation schemes of ZFC. Meanwhile every finitely axiomatized theory is of course recursively axiomatized.

Comment: I see. If you would point out concrete places in Smith's book (or anywhere else) as references for the results I need (up to your corrections), I will promise you a place in the Paradise at the Last Judgement.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I pointed to individual sections, I think you should just read them.

Comment: OK, it will take me some time, thank you!

Comment: Noah, this is like another planet for me. I see one more problem: you, logicians, use the expression "sentence true in $M$" as if there was another "true", different from "deducibility". For me "$\varphi$ is true in $M$" means that $\varphi$ is deducible in the corresponding theory which is an extension by definitions of the axiomatic set theory you choose. And this means in particular that what you denote by $Th(M)$ is not necessarily complete, since theoretically it is possible that neither $\varphi$, nor $\neg\varphi$ is deducible. Is is possible to translate this into  my language?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Just preface everything with the words "ZFC proves." Seriously, this resolves every difficulty. ZFC proves that to each structure, there is an associated complete theory. We don't have to believe that these structures or theories *exist* in any Platonist way; the sentence "The set of sentences true in a given structure is complete" is expressible and provable in ZFC. (In particular, there is a formula in the language of ZFC expressing "$X$ is a structure and $n$ is the Godel number of a sentence true in $X$.")

Comment: Ah, so there is a special theorem in ZFC... OK. What about MK, is there a similar theorem as well? I suppose, this explains the necessity to choose this set, $M$, and apparently in MK $M$ can be just a class, not necessarily a set, is that correct?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov MK extends ZFC, so proves everything ZFC does about sets. I believe that MK can also talk appropriately about proper-class-sized structures, but I am not familiar enough to comment on it. You write "so there is a special theorem in ZFC" - I feel obliged to comment that ZFC is *far too powerful* here; much, much less is necessary. Any reasonable set theory at all will prove that the theory of a structure exists and is complete, regardless of the structure itself.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thank you, this clarifies the satuation for me!

Comment: And again, I'll reiterate: there's nothing weirder about the theorem "The theory of a structure exists and is complete, regardless of the structure," ontologically speaking, than about the theorem "Every commutative ring which is not a field has a nontrivial proper ideal" - for a formalist, *both of them* have to be preceded by a phrase like "ZFC proves that ...". If you're e.g. comfortable informally thinking of rings as actual objects in order to understand theorems about them, that same comfort applies here; if not, you'll be equally uncomfortable with almost all mathematics.

Comment: Noah, I am reading Smith, the impression is that the situation is more complicated. As far as I understand, in his book the closest to us variant of the first Gödel incompleteness theorem has the number 19.6, and he formulates it for the so called "nice" theories which form a narrower class than recursively axiomatized, consistent and extending Q (IIUC). The second Gödel theorem is 25.2, and again it is for "nice" theories with a supplementary "derivability conditions". Is there a possibility to preserve your formulations (or at least to reformulate Smith in a simpler way)?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I won't be able to answer this satisfactorily until I get my hands on a copy of the book, which could be a couple days. But I'll try to respond.

Comment: Noah, can you also give a reference for this: <<ZFC proves that to each structure, there is an associated complete theory.>> ? This nevertheless looks strange for me.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov This is an easy application of Separation: the set of (Godel numbers of) sentences (in a given language) exists, and the relation "$M\models\varphi$" is definable in the language of ZFC (this is a good exercise; use Skolem functions). Now apply Separation to get the set of sentences which $M$ satisfies; this is the theory of $M$. For a lot of these basic facts, I don't know a reference - like any other subject in math, some straightforward things are left to the reader.

Comment: To clarify: I don't recommend actually writing down a definition of "$M\models\varphi$" in the language of set theory, but it's a good exercise to play around with ZFC to convince yourself that this can be done. If you can't do this after a while, I think it would make a good MSE question, but I do think that before you ask it you should play around with it for a bit.

Comment: But ultimately, if you won't be happy with an intuitive explanation and your goal is to really formalize these basic proofs, I think you're going to have to do that on your own (or with people who are similarly interested - they definitely exist, look into the formal proof/automated proof/computer-verified proof community); it's just not a point of interest for most mathematicians (including me, for all that I love formal proof).